# Why some functionality of my drupal site is different on different PCs?

Tags: 7

I created a site but when I log in from another PC (exact same site), some things are different.
Like on my laptop, my ajax loader is working beautifully but it lags on my office computer.
There is a message on successful image update (from media module) on my PC but there is no message in my laptop (however that should be the case).

What's happening here? I'm lost.

**UPDATE**

I saw a JavaScript error on my PC which is very much different than the JS error on my laptop. They are the same file, same webroot and same website. Even after turning off my development environment, I am not going further.

**UPDATE**

Problem Solved, the origin of the issue was JQuery Conflict. After defining different reference variables, my problem is free. Although I still don't understand why this was not a problem in my machine. Is there a mechanism that I'm missing?

Comment: different browsers or same?

Comment: Google Chrome, I tried on firefox, incognito of those and I checked in console. No luck yet

Comment: Is it related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)?

Comment: I checked. The problem was not limited to chrome. Thanks for the link @JimmyKo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the issue was Jquery Conflict. After defining different reference variables, my problem is free.